# iOS: How to dynamically create GMSMarker with custom info window?

Tags: ios, dictionary, marker

I create GMSMarker by a for loop, but GMSMarker does not support tag

```
for(int i=0;i<[self.shopDetailArray count];i++)
    {
        SHShopLocator *shop = [self.shopDetailArray objectAtIndex:i];

        GMSMarker *marker = [[GMSMarker alloc] init];
        marker.position = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(22.2783, 114.1589);
        marker.icon = [UIImage imageNamed:@"StoreLocator_pin"];
        marker.infoWindowAnchor = CGPointMake(0.3, 0.4);
        marker.map = self.map;
    }
```

so how do I recognise each marker when setting the custom markerInfoWindow?

```
  - (UIView *)mapView:(GMSMapView *)mapView markerInfoWindow:(GMSMarker *)marker
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the property **userData** of `GMSMarker`. You can store identifiers for each of markers!

#### Example

```
GMSMarker *marker = [[GMSMarker alloc] init];
marker.userData = @{@"marker_id":[NSNumber numberWithInt:12]};
```

Retrieve its value under:

```
- (UIView *)mapView:(GMSMapView *)mapView markerInfoWindow:(GMSMarker *)marker
{
    NSNumber *number = [marker.userData objectForKey:@"marker_id"];

    return mapView;
}
```

#### Documentation

> Marker data. You can use this property to associate an arbitrary
>   object with this marker. Google Maps SDK for iOS neither reads nor
>   writes this property. Note that userData should not hold any strong
>   references to any Maps objects, otherwise a loop may be created
>   (preventing ARC from releasing objects).

Comment: could you please show how to use it in swift coz it keep crash in swift thanks